# Database design for ads which can be promoted

Tags: database-design

I've got an ads table, with ads which can be promoted in two ways. They can be promoted in search results, so they come before the others, or they can be promoted to the front page, where a random selection of a few promoted ads are displayed. They are to be promoted for a certain time period.

I'm not sure how to best do this.

Another table for these promoted ads, and should I have a cron job to delete them once they expire, or... how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two concepts here, the `ad` and the `publication`.

Talking specifically about database design, it depends on how much information you want to add to the `publication`.

If it's just the type, you can do with a (possibly numeric) field in the same table.

If you need to add more `publication` specific info, you will be better off with a new table for these, this opens some interesting design questions like if an `ad` can have only one or many different `publications` (appear first and also include it in a mail newsletter for example).

Comment: no, one to many. the ad can be promoted at once both in the search results and on to the front page

Comment: Ok so clearly you need two tables. I think the odds of having a third kind of promotion in the near future are pretty high. Database design is one of the paces where you don't wanna go YAGNI

Comment: yes, i suppose. so how best to deal with expired promotions then?

Comment: You might never delete the promotions but have a __expires__ field, and when you query for the __promotions__ you do something like `Select * from promotions where expires > date.now()` or something (I'm pretty bad at sql but you hopefully understand what I mean)

Comment: With that strategy you could keep a historical record of all promotions, so that you can know which are the ads more promoted (better clients).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to have a second table, with a foreign key to the ads table, a column for the promotion rank (if desired), a column for the expiration date, and a column showing whether it's front page, search, or anything else you want to add later. (ie: 1 for search, 2 for front page, or 'search' and 'front_page' respectively)

When you select an ad to promote, you select from the AD_PROMOTION table and join it to the ADS table. Then, rather than using a cronjob to kill it when the expiration date has gone, you just demote or remove it when it gets selected.

```
while (ad != null) {
    ad = getRandomAd()
    if (ad.expires < now()) {
        demote(ad);
        ad = null; // Make sure you get another one
    }
}
```

Of course, you'd need something in place to make sure you wind up with an ad at some point, since you may not have any promoted ones.

```
ADS
AD_ID    INFORMATION
-----    -----------
1        'Max Power'
2        'Min Power'
3        'Homer Simpson'

AD_PROMOTION
AD_ID    LEVEL    EXPIRATION_DATE    PLACE
-----    -----    ---------------    -----
2        2        2010-02-18         'search'
3        3        2010-03-01         'front_page'
3        2        2010-04-01         'search'
```

Comment: but the ad can be promoted to the front page and in the search results both at once

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Edited my answer to take this into account.